# Created files in Unity are not added to the git (Rider) automatically

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, rider

When I create files in Unity editor or move already created files to another folder etc. - these files are not added to git by default. I have to manually add them to git in the Rider IDE. This becomes very annoing when I want to refactor project structure or when I add some prefabs and assets etc.

In Rider Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation I tried "silent: and "show options..." options, but to no avail. Also if I create file in Rider project structure It will be added by default.

gitignore file:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory

/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/

# Never ignore Asset meta data
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# TextMesh Pro files
[Aa]ssets/TextMesh*Pro/

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties
```

`git status` command  (.meta files were added to git when I marked whole folder to be added to git with this problem):

```
        new file:   Assets/Scripts/CatLikeLegacy.meta
        new file:   Assets/Scripts/CatLikeLegacy/EdgeVertices.cs.meta
        new file:   Assets/Scripts/CatLikeLegacy/FireTrail.cs.meta


... etc. meta files

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/
        .vscode/
        Assets/Build.meta
        Assets/Build/provinces.png.meta
        Assets/Build/provincesReference.png.meta
        Assets/Materials.meta

...etc ignored files .meta in common
```

When file created or moved git should automatically track this file.

**UPD:**
Tried to create new clean project in Unity and add git system from Rider - still this problem remains, new files are not tracked by Rider automatically (marked red).

Comment: Try the command line instead. Maybe also show what the output of `git status`?

Comment: >try the command line 
You mean try add new files with comand line? It is not that convinient either...

Comment: Convenient? I want to help you resolve an issue. There’s an issue and the best way to help resolve it is by using the command line.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that it will include a lot of manual work in future this way. Say I want to move all contents of one folder to another part of project - I will have to `git add` all files in that folder - It will be pretty annoying actually :)

Comment: The problem is not in that I can't add files to git, but is that files are not added to git automatically, I have to add them manually - whether from Rider IDE or from console `git add`

Comment: Were you ever able to add them automatically?

Comment: I am not quite shure, because when I've switched to Rider git structure was already present. But as I think of it - it is more likely that yes, Rider was tracking new files automatically before, I don't know why it is not working now however.

Comment: This looks related: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206344669-How-to-enable-git-auto-adding-files

Comment: Many thanks, @evolutionxbox! As I see from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52058 , this feature is not supported yet in Rider or any JetBrains product ;(

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. I'm glad this has been resolved.

Comment: @ВасилийМакаров I know it doesn't fix your problem, but I used Unity, Rider and have always used the CLI, you might be able to save yourself some time by reviewing if all the changes to git are wanted and then proceed to `git add --all` instead of adding them all one by one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing experience! I just tried out this method and it fits my request - it reduces manual work to one command. I need just to set up git ignore properly. I think your answer satisfies my question

Comment: @Antry I think it completly suits my question, you can answer and this question could be closed :)

Comment: @ВасилийМакаров Great ! I'm glad I was able provide you with a less labour-intensive solution :) I also added a clearer 'step-by-step' answer, for others who could encounter your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Unity with Rider, but I currently don't know of a solution using Rider-native functionalities.

But you could work around the problem by using the CLI (Command line interface) and adding all your files at once (instead of one-by-one) with :

```
git add --all
```

This does 'require' you to have a decent `.gitignore` so you don't include bloat Unity and Rider files.

Here is an example of such : [`.gitignore`](https://gist.github.com/IJEMIN/92c1ec8dc06cf0f853813cdaa5115a9f)

You might need to customize it a bit to your suiting; you can easily check what files would be included if you used `git add --all` by using the `git status` command, which should give you the necessary information to identify the exclusion patterns you need to add to your `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

As I see from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52058 thx to @evolutionxbox, this feature is not yet implemented for JetBrains products - which makes very annoying work flow in this IDE for unity. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta
```

by

```
!/[Aa]ssets/**/[\w\ \d\.]*.meta
```

as per [this link](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/3612/commits/7e903bc1b5e06e61dc14a66f78f7eab3647ba0fc) i found. It says

> Files can include spaces, which the current pattern doesn't capture.
> Example:  `Assets/Plugins/My Plugin.meta`